# Can endermen teleport up a hill with overhanging edge

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I am trying to build a killing spot for endermen. The idea is that I'm safe for their attack because I stand on a place that is only 2 high and they cannot get to me. I wait there and challenge them to come with a staring contest. This place is build on a small hill with an overhanging edge to stop spiders and other mobs from party crashing. A vertical cut would look something like this, with 'X' a solid block, '_' some air, 'p' the player and 'e' an enderman:

X X X
X p
X p
X X X X X X X X e
X X X X X X X _ e
X X X X X X X _ e
X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X

The problem is that it looks like the endermen refuse to teleport next to me and get their selves killed. Could there be some rule that they cannot teleport up the hill because it has an overhanging edge?

Comment: Just to get it out of the way, to aggro an Enderman properly, you have to look away slightly. If you stare them in the eye, they just shimmy and shake til the sun comes up

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Endermen can teleport up to 32m on each axis, so it should be entirely possible for the enderman to teleport up there.

However, from my tests, aggravated endermen that are already close to the player rarely seem to teleport unless hit. The spot they teleport to also seems to be randomly chosen when this happens, so your chance of them teleporting onto a ledge are relatively small.

Perhaps a farm like this might work out better:

```
X X X
X p
X p
X # X X e
X # _ X e
X # _ _ e
X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X
```

Where you can stare at the endermen, and then climb down the ladder (#) to hit them from a safe spot.

Comment: That explains the problem. Looks like it will be a pretty standard bunker then. :) thanks